# Error when launching gnome-terminal on Sway

Tags: gnome-terminal, wayland, sway

I've installed gnome-terminal and xorg-server-xwayland and now I am trying to launch gnome-terminal.

I already had an error caused by keycodes above 255. I deleted the keycodes above 255 and the problem get resolved but I've got an other problem :

```
[...]
glamor: No eglstream capable devices found
[...]

# Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0 : Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: Timeout was reached"
```

Anyone has an idea to solve this ?

May usefuls infos:

- OS: ArchLinux
- Kernel release: 5.2.8-arch1-1-ARCH
- X Server : Wayland
- Compositor : Sway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem with the help of https://askubuntu.com/questions/608330/problem-with-gnome-terminal-on-gnome-3-12-2 .

I didn't set my locale correctly, I put "lang" instead of "LANG" in my /etc/locale.conf ^^'

When I've set it correctly, I just reboot my computer and it works !